# Logic Pro updates from 9.1.8

Tags: software-update, logic

I have Logic Pro 9.1.8.  Can I update or upgrade this to Logic Pro X?

If so, how, and is there any cost?

Answer (score 2):

Logic Pro X is available on the Mac App Store for $200/£150.
There is no upgrade pricing for having purchased Logic Pro 9—everyone pays full price.